# Is "run the danger" in common usage?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in an article titled “[Building a Classier Image; Las Vegas Hotels Woo Blue Chip Visitors](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/11/13/business/building-a-classier-image-las-vegas-hotels-woo-blue-chip-visitors.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm)" by Andrew Pollak in The New York Times (November 13, 1997).

> Risks abound in this strategy, though. Visitors may balk at high room
>   rates if cheap ones are still plentiful, and giant hotels **run the
>   danger** of becoming impersonal. Most important, though: Can Las Vegas
>   absorb all these new rooms?

Can someone clarify if the phrase "***run the danger***" is improperly used, as I think it is?

I would replace "*danger*" with "*risk*", but I'm not sure on this correction because the phrase "*run the danger*" occurs on many occasions in The New York Times, it frequently occurs in others newspapers and, more generally, it has 365,000 hits on Google Search. So I am wondering if interchanging "*danger*" and "*risk*" in this phrase is in common usage nowadays, especially in spoken informal English; albeit it isn't idiomatically correct.

Comment: I get 404k results for "run the danger" and *8.9 million* results for "run the risk".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, but they are referred to only written English. However, I still think that "risk" and "danger" cannot be interchanged because these words are rather different in meaning.

Comment: @RégisRoux: 'the danger' and 'the risk' "rather different in meaning"? They sure share a lot though.

Comment: @Mitch: Both words have a spread of meaning, and those spreads overlap in OP's usage. But they have different idiomatic "grammar" even when they're semantically identical (you're *at risk* when you're *in danger*). In this case, the idiomatic association of *run* is stronger for *risk* - but both do occur, and are thus valid. But semantically equivalent, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As OP suspects, the standard "set phrase" is [run the **risk**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run%20the%20risk,run%20the%20danger&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

I don't think there's any solid argument against *run the danger* - it's just not a form of words people normally use.

Comment: I'm not completely satisfied, especially for the conclusion of your answer; but, I voted +1 as the graph is a nice work. Thank you @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Régis Roux: I don't quite follow. Do you mean you're looking for an explanation of *why* there's something incorrect about saying *"run the **danger**"*, based on some semantic or grammatical difference between *risk* and *danger*? I'd be pretty sure no such explanation exists, since *in toto*, plenty of competent native speakers say/write the less common version. Bear in mind it's "idiomatic" to use the verb *"to run"* like this in the first place (I suspect it came via *"run the gauntlet"*), so both versions depend on being heard and repeated. Success breeds success, is all.

Comment: I think your comment well explains the answer you posted. So, I'm going to accept.

Answer (score 1):

The popular idiom is *run the risk of*; when *risk* is replaced by a synonym, it is no longer accepted in the idiomatic sense. This has been brought out in [Nesselhauf](http://www.lancs.ac.uk/fass/projects/corpus/ZJU/ebooks/Nesselhauf_2005.pdf)'s doctoral thesis on collocations, later published by John Benjamins.

> "A treatment of an RC1 collocation, such as *run the risk of*, for example, seems most efficient if the learner is made aware that *run* in this sense only combines with *risk*, and that other combinations with similar nouns such as *run the danger of* or *run the peril of* are not possible or at least highly unusual.<sup>30</sup>"
>
> <sup>30</sup> *Run the danger* is sometimes used, but it is considerably less common than *run the risk* (11 occurrences in the BNC, as opposed to about 330 of *run a risk*, in a span of +/–6). It is also usually judged deviant by native speakers (4 native speakers were asked to judge the combination, all of whom considered it wrong or doubtful).
>   [Nadja Nesselhauf:  *Collocations in a Learner Corpus*, 2005, John Benjamins.]

However, ***run the danger*** as a set phrase seems to have peaked around 1940:
[image]

> **1930**: Were there no Loans Advisory Board with power to check borrowing, we should run the danger of having to face excessive credit demands by individual public bodies [Banking: journal of the American Bankers Association](http://books.google.com/books?id=qOkgAQAAMAAJ&q=%22run%20the%20danger%22&dq=%22run%20the%20danger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h9nrUNzXMMasrAea0YGYCg&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBTgU) - Volume 23 - Page 391
>   **1936**: ... a tract of open country where they would run the danger of being recognized and taken. [The Spectator](http://books.google.com/books?id=S3Y_AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA932&dq=%22run%20the%20danger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VdjrUMPzH8ztrQfksoGQAQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA) - Volume 156 - Page 932
>   **1939**: ... believe we built beyond our normal trade requirements, and unless we appraise our future with some degree of intelligence, do we not run the danger of a similar repetition? [Bankers magazine](http://books.google.com/books?id=rp4SAQAAMAAJ&q=%22run%20the%20danger%22&dq=%22run%20the%20danger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1tjrUKnFDsOrrAfz4oCICA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBDgU) - Volume 139 - Page 406

And continues to be in use, especially in journalistic writing, as is seen from the OP's citation from the NYT.

Answer (score -1):

While "run the risk" is more popular, it contains an internal logic that "run the danger" lacks. In gambling, one runs various ways in the games at hand. Run the table. Run the deck. A run of winning/losing. Run a bet (less common).

So running a risk is like running a betting plan or running a deck counting scheme. Running a (or the) danger sounds derivative and less supported, but it also sounds more emphatic. Running a risk sounds more primary.

Comment: But 'It ['run the danger'] is also usually judged deviant by native speakers (4 native speakers were asked to judge the combination, all of whom considered it wrong or doubtful).' [Kris's answer].